# SQL : How to select a column based on partial string of the column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem here.

I would like to select a column based on a max(timestamp) of that column, but I'm stuck at retrieving it. Let's say I have the following data:

```
Comments
========
abcd 2012/08/14 8:03:03 AM more data inside <- I want to retrieve this
hshsh 2012/08/13 1:03:03 AM some other comments
hahhah 2012/08/10 8:03:03 PM test it.
```

My SQL to retrieve the max(timestamp) is

```
select max(substr(comments, instr(comments, '2012'), instr(comments, 'M') - 6)) from TABLEA
```

but how do I select  this column based on this statement?

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to do this:

```
select comments from tableA where comments like (select max(substr(comments,   instr(comments, '2012'), instr(comments, 'M') - 6)) from TABLEA)
```

I was hoping to get the first row of the comments column but there is no output.
I hope I'm not too vague... I'm using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
  select 
  comments, substr(comments, instr(comments, '2012'), instr(comments, 'M') - 6) YEAR
  from TABLEA
  order by substr(comments, instr(comments, '2012'), instr(comments, 'M') - 6) desc
  where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Alfasin, that's pretty close but I want to get comments instead of the max(year) instead, wonder if it's possible. :-)

Comment: I can't test it right now - but I believe this should work. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from 
(
    select comments
    from TABLEA
    order by substr(comments, instr(comments, '2012'), instr(comments, 'M') - 6) desc
)
where rownum = 1
```